# Run C# application on Windows without installing any runtime

Tags: c#, .net

Probably a naive question but...

What I want:

- I would like to write a more modern C# application with .NET 6-7...
- Possibly use `dotnet` command line compilation and `vscode` as editor

Prerequisites:

- No runtime installation
- small executable size (cannot have a single application of 160Mb)

After reading a lot around I understand that:

- .NET Framework comes pre-installed on Windows
- .NET (Core) should instead be installed

Can you confirm that I am hitting a wall in the sense that with these requisites is better to stick with `.NET Framework` (no installation) and `Visual Studio` as Compiler?

I guess that there is no way to use `dotnet` to compile for `.NET Framework`?

More info:

- The application is a WinForm application
- I have tried to configure the .csproj to use .NET but `dotnet` is not finding the .NET Framework installed (maybe is this the real point). It only finds .NET Core sdks

Comment: You can't do that with .NET Framework. Self-contained executables are a .NET (Core) feature

Comment: "I guess that there is no way to use dotnet to compile for .NET Framework?" There absolutely is - just use a target of "net48" for example. You should look into self-contained executables too, but they may be too big.

Comment: .NET 6 is .NET *Core* 6 by the way

Comment: I know that self-contained are .NET (Core), but they are too big in size for my actual needs)

Comment: .NET 6 is also .NET Core. As for too big, what do you mean? They're certainly not 160MB and the actual output can be [trimmed aggressively](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/trimming/trim-self-contained). It seems that at least 100MB is your application's output, not the runtime itself

Comment: Perhaps the real question is how to trim your self-contained executable? Using app trimming an executable could be as small as 35MB. What are the other 125MB for?

Comment: If your application really needs those 125MB of DLLs you won't gain anything even if you eliminate the runtime completely and use a framework-dependent deployment to a machine that already has the .NET 6 runtime.

Comment: The application itself is some kB, what reaches 160MB is the packing of .NET runtime publishing as a single file E.G `dotnet publish -r win10-x64 -c Release /p:PublishSingleFile=true `

Comment: Trying to TRIM a WinForm .NET 7.0 application is not yet supported with `dotnet`, in fact it gives a clear error message about this.

Comment: The `.exe` file is just a bootstrapper, not your actual application executables. You never mentioned you have a Windows Forms application. Add enough information in your question so people can help. What type of application, what does it contain, what did you try? What happens if you create a new WinForms application with just a single empty form? That's the baseline you need to keep in mind

Comment: Besides, there aren't many options - either you create a self-contained executable or you install the .NET runtime. As for `vscode as editor`, the main advantage of Windows Forms is the Visual Studio designer. You lose that if you use Visual Studio Code. If you're willing to give that up, why not look at MAUI, which was built with trimming and non-VS building in mind?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I understand the point. My final possible point is simply using `dotnet` as builder and this seems possible for what @JonSkeet told. This could be ok for me. Just that `dotnet` does not show `.NET Framework sdks` installed and only `.NET Core`

Comment: Many (not all, but many) features of "modern" C# are enabled by using `<LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>` in your (new-style) project file, as this gives you access to the latest version of C# minus the features that really need runtime support (like explicit interface implementations). If you're developing WinForms .NET Core doesn't yet bring you much in the way of improvements; may as well stick to the versions of Framework that are guaranteed to come with the operating system.

Comment: You can't generate self-contained applications with .NET Framework, so what's the point? You'll have to install the correct runtime anyway. Although at the moment [supported Windows versions have 4.7 at least](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies)